# What do we need std::as_const() for?

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, type-traits

C++11 has given us [`std::add_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv); with C++17, we have a new structure - [`std::as_const()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const). The former just tacks a `const` before the type you provide it with. The second one is a proper (template of a) function, not type trait, which seems to do the same - except for when the type is an rvalue-reference, in which case it cannot be used.

I don't quite understand the motivation for providing `std::as_const()`. Why do we need it in addition to `std::add_const`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

"Need" is a strong word... `std::as_const` exists because it's useful, not strictly necessary. Since it's a function rather than a trait, we can use it to  "add const" to actual *values* rather than to *types*.

More specifically: Suppose I have some variable `my_value` and I want to treat it as a `const`, but not copy it. Before C++17 I would need to write:

```
static_cast<const MyType&>(my_value)
```

and if I don't want to specify the type explicitly, it would be:

```
static_cast
   <std::add_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(my_value)>> &>
   (my_value)
```

or if you want to get down and dirty, and use C-style casting:

```
(const decltype(my_value) &) (&my_value)
```

all of which are annoying and verbose.

Instead of these, with C++17 now write `std::as_const(my_value)` and that's all there is to it.

Notes:

- This function is disabled for rvalue references even though it works just fine for them. The reason is to help you avoid inadvertantly keeping a reference to a temporary past its destruction. As @NicolBolas explains, if you write something like:

  ```
  for(auto &x : std::as_const(returns_container())) { /* do stuff with x */ }
  ```

  then the returned container's lifetime ends before the first iteration of the loop. Very easy to miss!
- For additional (?) information, consult the official proposition of this utility function: [P007R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0007r1.html), by Adam David Alan Martin and Alisdair Meredith.

Comment: "*I'm not entirely clear why the deletion for rvalue references is necessary though.*" Because C++'s temporary lifetime extension rules don't work correctly if you tried to use `as_const` on them. If you ever call `as_const` on a temporary, you *will* get a reference to a destroyed object.

Comment: @Quentin: Really? IIANM, [reference collapsing](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) should kick in, shouldn't it?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks. But - won't the temporary live until the the statement in which the `as_const()` is used, is fully executed? If not, can you link to an explanation?

Comment: @einpoklum: It will life to the end of the full expression. But if you're doing something like `for(auto &val : std::as_const(returns_container()))`, the "full expression" ends before the `for` loop starts. Whereas if you had used `returns_container()` directly, the temporary's lifetime would extend to the entire `for` loop. Better to prevent people from making that mistake up-front.

Comment: `std::as_const()` is particularly useful to select the `const` overload of a set. Given `std::map<int,int> m`, `m[0]` and `as_const(m)[0]` are quite different.

Comment: @YSC `as_const(m)[0]` is ill-formed, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Caleth I was thinking of `at()` but wrote `[]` as an habit.

Comment: @einpoklum I mean in the "Before C++17" case. `decltype(my_value)` would yield `T&`, which `std::add_const` would leave unchanged, thus the cast would be a no-op.

Comment: Side note: I don't think you should be using `const_cast` in your first two examples, when a `static_cast` would suffice. As a general rule, you should use the weakest kind of cast that will achieve the desired conversion. `const_cast` should be reserved for when it's really needed: to _remove_ const. `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` are the most dangerous casts, and to use them when not needed is to discard the safety of the type system.

Comment: @Oktalist: I guess you're right; I was using the same cast as in the proposal.

Comment: @Oktalist `static_cast` may create a temporary object if you accidentally cast to a different type as the operand is, `const_cast` will not allow to do this, the difference may be only in cv qualifiers

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki good point. It could also downcast an inheritance hierarchy in a potentially undefined way. It seems there is no perfect answer to which cast to use here. Which is a good reason to use `as_const`.

Comment: "*Because C++'s temporary lifetime extension rules don't work correctly...*" Is there anything in the works to fix this @NicolBolas?  Or is it not considered broken?

Answer (score 9):

You may want to overload const, no-const and force one of the overloads:

```
template<class T> [[nodiscard]]
T twice(T const& t){return t + t;}

template<class T>
void twice(T& t){t += t;}
```

You can protect the input by adding `const` and use the non-modifying overload.

```
double t = 5.;
twice(t); // t == 10

double const u = 5.;
double ux2 = twice(u); // ux2 == 10, u == 5.;

double v = 5.;
double vx2 = twice(std::as_const(v)); // vx2 == 10., v==5. It saves you from
                                      // creating a const-reference
                                      // `double const& ucr = u;` just to pass
                                      // to the function.
```

I am not saying it is a good design, it is just to illustrate the point.
It is a matter of time to find a more useful case.

---

**A better name for `std::as_const` could have been `std::protect` IMO.**

Comment: "A better name would be `std::protect`"
+1. This explains it better than most actual explanations.

Comment: I am seeing an uptick of votes since this video was released: "C++ Weekly - Ep 291 - Start Using `as_const`" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w996YXhkpkE)